# How can I customize validation error messages in Woost?

Tags: python, content-management-system

I have a model with a **schema.Date** member with a restriction on its maximum allowed value. The validation works correctly but I need to display a different translation for the generated error.

Can I customize the translation of the **cocktail.schema.exceptions.MaxValueError** error for my model?

Comment: Try it and let us know what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done, but the exact procedure changes a bit after woost 2.11 "pacman" and newer releases. Also, it can feel a bit convoluted if you are not familiar with how Cocktail obtains translations for schema members.

You want to define a translation key matching this pattern:

**Pacman and newer:**

```
myapp.models.mymodule.MyModel.members.my_member.errors.cocktail.schema.exceptions.MaxValueError
```

**Older releases:**

```
MyModel.my_member-error: cocktail.schema.exceptions.MaxValueError
```

Notice how the key composes the name of your member with the type of the exception that you want to define the description for.

Note that although the Pacman convention seems overly long compared to the more compact pattern used in previous versions, it applies proper namespacing to avoid naming collisions and, furthermore, it takes advantage of the new .strings file format to allow you to write something like this:

```
[myapp.models.mymodule.MyModel]

    [members]

        [my_member]
        # Your member's name, and other related strings

            [errors]
            # You can put all your error customizations here

                [cocktail.schema.exceptions.MaxValueError]
                en: Member XYZ is too high!
                es: El campo XYZ es demasiado grande!
```

The equivalent on older releases would be to add the following on your strings.py file:

```
translations.define(
    "MyModel.my_member-error: cocktail.schema.exceptions.MaxValueError",
    en = u"Member XYZ is too high!",
    es = u"El campo XYZ es demasiado grande!"
)
```

Regardless of which version you are using, you can take a look at the [cocktail.schema.Member.translate_error](https://bitbucket.org/whads/cocktail/src/mezcal/cocktail/schema/member.py?fileviewer=file-view-default#member.py-527) method to see what Cocktail does under the hood to obtain the translation.

Also, if you are dealing with validation errors you are probably using a schema adapter. If that's the case, you will want to think if your custom translation belongs on the model or on your adapted form schema, depending on wether your customization is appropiate for any scenario where this field produces this error, or if it only makes sense on your particular form. If you want to confine it to your form, replace myapp.models.MyModel with the qualified name of your form.

Finally, you may want to use a dynamic translation, to include details from the error object into your translation:

**Pacman and newer:**

```
[myapp.models.mymodule.MyModel]

    [members]

        [my_member]
        # Your member's name, and other related strings

            [errors]
            # You can put all your error customizations here

                [cocktail.schema.exceptions.MaxValueError(member, error)]
                en: Member t{member} is too high! The maximum permitted value is ${member.translate_value(error.max)}
                es: El campo t{member} es demasiado grande! El valor máximo permitido es ${member.translate_value(error.max)}
```

**Older releases:**

```
translations.define(
    "MyModel.my_member-error: cocktail.schema.exceptions.MaxValueError",
    en = lambda instance: u"Member %s is too high! The maximum allowed value is %s" % (translations(instance.member, instance.member.translate_value(instance.max))),
    es = lambda instance: u"El campo %s es demasiado grande! El valor máximo permitido es %s" % (translations(instance.member, instance.member.translate_value(instance.max))),
)
```

Comment: Hi Marti, thank you so much for your detailed explanation. My custom error translation works like a charm !